# In Heart of Darkness, why did native Africans love Kurtz?

Tags: joseph-conrad, heart-of-darkness

In *Heart of Darkness* by Joseph Conrad, why did native Africans love Kurtz despite his violent nature?

Comment: Please provide some quotes that lead you to believe that the Africans "loved" Kurtz.  The quotes that most lead you this this interpretation.